# Conditionally modifying columns in pyspark dataframe nested structs

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe representing CDC messages with the following schema.

```
root
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- after: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _change_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- before: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _change_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- source: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- connector: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- transaction: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ts_ms: long (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
```

Sometimes, the before column could be null(representing INSERTs) or the after column could be null(representing DELETEs) but never both. For UPDATEs, they would both be non-null.

I want to modify the spark dataframe such that I add 2 fields an and b to the 'before' and 'after' nested struct columns but ONLY if they are non-null. I also want to preserve the other fields as is.

This is how it should look after the transformation.

```
root
 |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- after: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _change_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true) <--new field
 |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true) <--new field
 |    |-- before: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _change_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- a: string (nullable = true) <--new field
 |    |    |-- b: string (nullable = true) <--new field
 |    |-- op: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- source: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- connector: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- transaction: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- ts_ms: long (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
```

I tried the following code but it does not work as expected and errors out when I read in null before rows sometimes.

```
df.withColumn(
            "value",
            F.struct(
                F.col("value.after").withField("a", "a").withField("b", "b").alias("after"),
                F.col("value.before").withField("a", "a").withField("b", "b").alias("before"),
                F.col("value.op"),
                F.col("value.source"),
                F.col("value.transaction"),
                F.col("value.ts_ms"),
            ),
        )
```

Is there a better way to do this? Ideally I'd like to do the transformation without having to make a reference to the other columns like op, source, transaction, ts_ms like I am currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way. You can use the `withField` function to add the additional fields directly to the struct column `value`, also using this approach you dont have to reference the other columns

```
value = (
    F.col('value')
     .withField('after.a', F.lit('a'))
     .withField('after.b', F.lit('b'))
)

df = df.withColumn('value', value)
```